# EJS injection into method before <%= render (express view helpers)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I develop a module called express helpers that makes ruby on rails-like view helpers. I am trying to make a form_for method similar to RoR but I am running into difficulty with how ejs works

This is how I want the view to work:

```
<% form_for("user", {multipart: true}, function(f){ %>
  <%= f.label_for("username") %>
  <%= f.text_field("username") %>
  <%= f.submit() %>
<% }) %>
```

Now I have been trying to just inject the form tags around the inner tags but that is not working either.
And I have tried putting the form_for method in a <%= tag but it cannot handle be separated
example <%=  form_for("user", {multipart: true}, function(f){ %><% }) %>

this is my current method code

```
helpers.form_for = function(form_obj_string, html_options, formcall){
    var form_obj = this[form_obj_string]

    var old = formcall.toString();
    var args = old.substring(old.indexOf("(") + 1, old.indexOf(")"));
    var scr = old.substring(old.indexOf("{") + 1, old.lastIndexOf("}") - 1);
    eval("t.formcall = function (" + args + "){" + scr + " }");

    var form_helpers = {
        formObj: form_obj,
        label_for: function(element_string, html_options){
            helpers.label_for(form_obj_string+"["+element_string+"]", html_options)
        },
        text_field: function(element_string, html_options){
            helpers.text_field_tag(form_obj_string+"["+element_string+"]", html_options["value"], html_options)
        },
        text_area: function(element_string, html_options){
            helpers.text_area_tag(form_obj_string+"["+element_string+"]", html_options["value"], html_options)
        },
        submit: helpers.submit_tag
    }

    return helpers.form_tag('/'+form_obj_string+'s',html_options) + formcall(form_helpers) + helpers.form_end_tag();
}
```

I have the helpers working no problem basically all I want to do is inject the form tags around the body of the form in a relatively intuitive way.

Any ideas or discouragments?

Comment: yes but it was quite in depth so if you want to take a look at my source you can find it in my npm module here https://github.com/tanema/express-helpers